# The field in returned json is an id referenceing to other json, how to parse it

Tags: java, android, json

Hi guys I encountered a problem on handling json on Android today. The json I got from the web service looks like the below:

e.g. from https://serviice.somewebite.com/list.json, I got this :

```
 {

    "task_id": 5,

    "profile_id": 3,

    "text": "{profileName} wrote {taskName}",

    "created_at": "2015-08-10",

    "event": "post"
},

{

    "task_id": 6,

    "profile_id": 2,

    "text": "{profileName} wrote {taskName}",

    "created_at": "2015-10-24",

    "event": "post"

},

 ...... (and many similar entities)
```

the task_id is actually an id linking to other remote json, for the first entity, task_id = 5, which I should get the task json from https://serviice.somewebite.com/task/5.json, like the below:

```
{

"id": 5,

"name": "Clean house",

"description": "Clean every room in the house",

"state": "assigned",

}
```

And it is the similar way to get the profile json in the list.json file.

I have been handling json with `pojo + retrofit + GSON` before, but all the content are in one json, not like this.

What I want is getting all the needed jsons and show them in a listview including created_at(in list.json), task_description(in task.json), task_name(in task.json)

Currently I can only figure out one way to hanlde it. First get the list.json , and then scan the task ids and profile ids in list.json, and then get all the needed json via multiple asynchronous http requests. Seems too much boiler plate code here.

Is there an existing `library/framework` for this scenario? I am on Android platform using Java. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Make a hashmap of tasks, and then refer to it by task_id.

Comment: thanks. It seems that I have to do it manually. There is no existing library for this case.